# Use C# class implemented in shared project with Nlua

Tags: c#, lua, scripting, nlua

I want to use Nlua in my Project. My project setup is: 
I have a shared project where I implemented my logic, and several platform specific projects that use this shared project.

I now want to use classes defined in this shared project inside a lua function I execute with Nlua. Problem is, this doesn't work.

```
lua.DoString(@"import('Platformspecific_Project_AssemblyName', 'Platformspecific_Project_Namespace') SomceClass.StaticMethod()");
```

This works fine. But if I now want to use a class defined in the shared project, this won't work:

```
lua.DoString(@"import('Platformspecific_Project_Assembly','Shared_Project_Namespace') SomeSharedClass.StaticMethod()");
```

The error I get is:

```
 Additional information: [string "chunk"]:1: attempt to index global 'SomeSharedClass' (a nil value)
```

From what I read (I'm new to lua by the way) this error occurs if I want to do something to a variable before it is defined (because lua files are parsed from start to the end, though I'm not shure about this.)

My question is: How can I use Methods and Classes defined in a shared project with Nlua? I'm pretty shure I got something wrong with Assemblies, but it seems there's not much documentation on this topic.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share project doesn't create an Assembly (.dll), you need to use the final Assembly.

Or you could use a PCL as well . Otherwise the `LoadAssembly` from NLua will fail

Thank you.